# Building PowerPoint Add-In: What to do if desired function cannot be done with Office JavaScript API?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I am currently building my first PowerPoint add-in, following instructions from the Office Add-ins documentation

The documentation suggests building add-in's with the Office JavaScript API. **However, I am wondering what should I do if the feature I want is not possible with the API?**

For example: I want to create a button in my add-in that applies 'send to front' (same as what can be done with the existing PowerPoint GUI) to the selected shape, but I couldn't find the equivalent API to do so.

The question / example also extends to any other complex features I want to have with my add-in that isn't doable with the Office Javascript API.

A potential solution I found is with [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/), and the functionalities do cover "nearly every operation that you can perform with a mouse, keyboard, or a dialog box can also be automated by using VBA"

However, I couldn't find any documentation on how to run VBA within a add-in built with the Office JavaScript API.

Is it just a matter of needing to build an add-in not using the API? Or is there a workaround?

Apologies upfront if this is a stupid question and there is a simple answer.

Comment: First off, it's NOT a stupid question. Microsoft is hellbent on getting everyone to use the Javascript API but hasn't put the effort into PowerPoint to make this a practical approach. Do you need your PowerPoint add-in to run under Windows, Mac, Web and mobile devices, or is running on Windows and/or Mac desktop versions sufficient? If the latter, you'll probably be better off just creating the add-in in VBA and VBA only, leaving JS out of the mix entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to call VBA from Office.js or vice versa. We're stuck with choosing one language or the other and doing everything with that.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thank you for the answer - running on Windows is sufficient and will look to leave JS out of the mix entirely.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thank you for the clarification - appreciate it.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. If you run into questions using VBA, start a new thread here. Lots of able folks will help out.